# Subresource Integrity on CSS-included fonts over CDN (e.g. font-awesome)

Tags: html, css, fonts, subresource-integrity

How would one employ [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) for resources included by a `.css` file included over a CDN.

For example, if you include this in your HTML:

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">`

This will load fonts included via the CSS, such as `url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0')`  Of course, these fonts could be tampered with, to take advantage of some untold browser exploit, so it makes sense to force hash checking in them, too.

How can one tell a browser to perform the SRI-hash of the `fontawesome-webfont.*` files that are loaded via the `.css`?

*Note*: It looks like sub-sub-resource hashes are [not yet supported](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-subresource-integrity/issues/40), though I'm not sure if that's the latest.

Comment: Note that font CDNs may deliberately vary the CSS and fonts in ways that prevent assigning a static hash: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/473

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, subresources of resources that have a valid integrity and CORS header shouldn't need anything more. At least, that seems to be the case with CSP enforced on Opera.